# How can i append a material from a blend file using python script

Tags: python, materials, scripting, add-on, shaders

I wan't a script that could append a particular material only from a particular blend file so that i can just run the script and the material is there

Answer (score 1):

This links a number of named materials from **materiallibrary.blend**

```
import bpy
# Load materials
bpy.ops.wm.link(filepath="materiallibrary.blend/Material/LL_WireTrans", directory="materiallibrary.blend/Material/", filename="LL_WireTrans", files=[{"name":"LL_Clay", "name":"LL_Clay"}, {"name":"LL_Glass", "name":"LL_Glass"}, {"name":"LL_WireHold", "name":"LL_WireHold"}, {"name":"LL_WireTrans", "name":"LL_WireTrans"}], relative_path=True)
```

I did not write the above, Blender created it for me. Run `blender.exe --debug-all` and manually link your required materials, then in the console will be the python code generated, similar to the above.

Because of the **--debug-all** you will will also get a ton of other stuff that you will need to sort through.

Link to the project I use this in
[Camera-track-endevour](https://github.com/robgithub/camera-track-endevour)

Comment: Wow, thumbs up for --debug-all !